# How to compress pdf file with nodejs?

Tags: node.js, pdf, ghostscript

I have tried to compress using ghostscript but no luck.
Anyone has any alternative that is free and working?

Comment: What exactly did you try with Ghostscript ? It's not intended as a compression tool, if you make certain choices then it will produce a smaller PDF file but in general it produces the same output as the input, so I wouldn't expect it to get smaller. What compromises on quality are you prepared to accept to reduce the size of the PDF file ?

Comment: Yes i want reduce the size of pdf file

Comment: Any other ways because ilovepdf, smallpdf and many more are doing it but don't know how.

Comment: Without seeing an example input file there's no way anyone can help you at all. We've already asked what compromises in quality you are prepared to accept in order to reduce the file size; you haven't replied. If you know there is software which gets the result you want then you could post the original and an example 'compressed' output file and we could at least figure out what's been done. Without any more information to go on you aren't likely to get any more help.

Comment: I can sacrifice text and image quality

Comment: You won't get much out of text, unless you are doing something unusual with the parameters. You can downsample images, if they are high quality. Check https://ghostscript.com/doc/current/VectorDevices.htm#COMMON under 'Distiller Parameters'. You can individually choose to change the downsampling type, threshold and compression of monochrome, gray or colour images (you also need to set Downsample..*..Images to true for the relevant type of image). Of course if your images are already low resolution this won't do anything. There is no guarantee of any reduciton in size.

Answer (score -1):

```
 var inputFile = req.body.path
    outputFilePath = Date.now() + "output" + path.extname(req.body.path);
    console.log(outputFilePath);
  
    exec(
      `gs \ -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dSAFER \ -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \ -dCompatibilityLevel=1.3 \ -dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook \ -dEmbedAllFonts=true \ -dSubsetFonts=true \ -dAutoRotatePages=/None \ -dColorImageDownsampleType=/Bicubic \ -dColorImageResolution=72 \ -dGrayImageDownsampleType=/Bicubic \ -dGrayImageResolution=72 \ -dMonoImageDownsampleType=/Subsample \ -dMonoImageResolution=72 \ -sOutputFile=${outputFilePath} \ ${inputFile}`,
      (err, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (err) {
          res.json({
            error: "some error takes place",
          });
        }
        res.json({
          path: outputFilePath,
        });
      }
    );
```